# objective c - for loop with two if statements

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, for-loop, uiviewcontroller

I'm building an app and I am almost done.

Trouble is this: I have a for loop with two if statements that is not working properly, and I just can't see what is wrong.

Here is the code:

```
for (Tickets *items in _feedItems){
    if ([resultText.text isEqual:(id) items.ticketNumber]) {
        if ([items.ticketDate isEqualToString: @"0"]) {

            status.text = @“YES”;


            NSString *date = resultText.text;
            NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString     
                                              stringWithString:kPostURL];
            [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", kDate, 
                                               date]];
            [postString setString:[postString 
                                      stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:
                                                                            [NSURL URLWithString:postString]];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request 
                                                      delegate:self startImmediately:YES];


            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" 
                                                     bundle:nil];
            UIViewController *View = [storyboard 
                                         instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Approved"];

            [self presentViewController:View animated:NO completion:NULL];

        }
        break;

    }
    else {
        status.text = @“NO”;

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" 
                                                 bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *View = [storyboard 
                                     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NotApproved"];

        [self presentViewController:View animated:NO completion:NULL];
    }
 }
```

This code always throws me to the ViewController NotApproved, and never to the Approved ViewController; even if it is approved and the POST to the database is executed.

Any help would be much obliged!

Comment: Unrelated question: If multiple tickets are NotApproved, are you expecting multiple NotApproved view controllers to be presented in sequence?  Or are you only interested in getting the status of the _single_ ticket specified by resultText.text?  If the latter is your intention, then maybe the `else` part should be attached to the _inner_ `if`.

Comment: I tried that, and it works for a ticket that is in the database, but if it is a ticket that is not registered then nothing happens. I deleted the break, and replaced it with the else statement (and deleted the outer else statement).

Comment: Case when it works: I get the Approved ViewController the first time, and the NotApproved the second time, because it is "marked as used" in the database. That is great! But if I use a ticket that is not in the database, then nothing happens....the button gets pushed...and it does not change ViewController.

Comment: In your question, I think it would be better if you added an explanation of exactly what you want to achieve because it's not obvious from the code (eg: Are you only interested in acting on one specific ticket, What defines whether a ticked is approved/notapproved, What should happen if it's approved, What should happen if it's not approved, etc).

Comment: Even more important: Do some debugging by adding NSLog statements to show what the code is actually doing or what data it is seeing.  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger and seen the actual execution flow and confirmed it does what you expect?  Where it doesn't do what you expect, log the variable values, include the results of the debugging in the question.

Comment: Another thing is that without a `break` (meaning you're interested in one ticket), trying to present multiple view controllers sequentially will possibly fail (so it may present the NotApproved VC and then for another ticket do the POST but its present VC fails).

Comment: What I want to achieve is to show ViewController Approved, the first time a ticket enters the system, and ViewController NotApproved the second time it enters the system, and finally I want to show ViewController NotApproved if a ticket enters the system, which is not in the database.

Comment: Maybe I'll try with a separate function for the tickets that are not in the system....

Comment: Thank you for your help!!! I got it working by making a separate function for the tickets that are not in the system. A case of: reality is a lot simpler then I think it is :) Nice playing ping pong with you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if ([resultText.text isEqual:(id) items.ticketNumber])`  problem is here, you are comparing string to id. id could be anything String, Array, Dictionary etc. Convert into text first, then do comparison else it will throw error every time.

Comment: He said the `POST` is executing. That means the `if` is going into the first block.

Comment: Ok should I write: if ([resultText.text isEqual: items.ticketNumber]) ?

Comment: items.ticketNumber is string or integer ? seems to me an integer

Comment: items.ticketNumber is a string (which contains numbers).

Comment: If I delete the NotApproved ViewController, then the Approved ViewController shows

Comment: then try with  if ([resultText.text isEqualToString: items.ticketNumber]), it should work. You can NSLog both values to verify if contains same text.
Please note its isEqualToString instead of isEqual

Comment: Thank you for your help! I made a separate function for the tickets, that are not in the system. Did not try the last suggestion.